# Pass parameters as option in custom getopts script in bash

Tags: bash, getopt, getopts

I'd like to pass options as a parameter. E.g.:

```
mycommand -a 1 -t '-q -w 111'
```

The script cannot recognize a string in quotes. I.e it gets only part of the string.

`getopts` works the same - it see only `-q`.

For custom getopts I use similar script (example):

```
while :
do
    case $1 in
        -h | --help | -\?)
            # Show some help
            ;;
        -p | --project)
            PROJECT="$2"
            shift 2
            ;;
        -*)
            printf >&2 'WARN: Unknown option (ignored): %s\n' "$1"
            shift
            ;;
        *)  # no more options. Stop while loop
            break
            ;;
        --) # End of all options
        echo "End of all options"
            shift
            break
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: How do you expect the script to use `'-q -w 111'`? The same as if it weren't quoted?

Comment: I use calling to another script. `anotherscript $customOptions`

Comment: There is no `-t` in the `getopts` parsing section...?

Comment: @chepner you could just use `set - $@` at the start

Comment: You really never want to use unquoted `$@`; you lose information about which arguments may have included whitespace.

Comment: @anishsane, yeah, because there is an example.

Comment: @chepner That was the point wasn't it ?

Comment: @User112638726 No, you lose *all* whitespace. `"$@"` keeps the distinction between  `-q "foo bar"` and `-q foo bar`, for instance.

Comment: @chepner You said `The same as if it weren't quoted?` I supplied a way where it was the same as if it wasn't quoted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstand the question, but `getopts` seems to work for me:

```
while getopts a:t: arg
do
    case $arg in
        a)  echo "option a, argument <$OPTARG>"
            ;;
        t)  echo "option t, argument <$OPTARG>"
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Run:

```
bash gash.sh -a 1 -t '-q -w 111'
option a, argument <1>
option t, argument <-q -w 111>
```

Isn't that what you want?  Maybe you missed the `:` after the options with arguments?

Comment: Hm, I checked it by similar and didn't work. I'll check your example out. Thanks!

Comment: Your script works well. Seem I've made mistake somewhere and it didn't work for me. 
thanks!